# While adding a canvas and then text into a gameobject, Canvas and text size problem

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

I am working on a 2d project with unity engine. (I am a newbie)
[image: first image]
As you can see in image I already have a canvas for UI elements but also I have gameobjects under player element. I want to add text inside "govde" element. but when I add it;
[image]
at left bottom you can see my game. but canvas and text size is HUGE.
I dont know what is wrong with my game or canvas but I could not solve this. 
By the way my gun works well so there are no errors in game. here is a photo of game scene;
[image]

Thank you for any kind of help. Have a nice day:)

EDIT : I Wanted to show the text box I wanted; please consider the numbers are so small. What I am asking is when width:2 and height:1 ok my textbox fits inside that car but since it is so small, i cannot show even 1 characters inside text box even if I make font size : 1. My english is not perfect sorry if I make any mistake. Here is picture; 
[image]
and IF I Make bigger to everything, They don't fit to my game screen. I tried to move camera to far away but that did not changed to my Game Screen.
[image]

LASTLY: When I add my a text inside my UI CANVAS, it perfectly fits. But when I add same textbox to game object called Player as I needed, it is TOO BIG
[image]

SOLUTION : For anybody who deals with same problem try to create a text object inside a UI CANVAS, after that create another canvas inside game object. And lastly, drag textbox into second canvas . That solved all my problems. My second canvas is still huge and when I make it smaller my textbox gets smaller and smaller so I cannot use it again but I let canvas to be huge, no problem for me at all. Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you created is the tiny black ‘New Text’ above the word basla. The canvas isn't actually viewable, you can add a ‘Panel’ underneath to confirm its size.

edit set font size and change width and height of text

keep scale at 1,1,1, track all the parent scale of each parent object, they do multiply in scale as you go down, so if one parent has scale 2,2,2 and its parent has scale 3,3,3 by the time you get to the text at 1,1,1 its scaled to 6,6,6 so keep this in mind and reorganize you hierarchy as needed

Comment: I know text box is smaller then canvas but even though I set its scale to what I need, I cannot see anything inside it because it is too small. even 1 font size is too big to see. I tried to add panel but nothing changed.

Comment: I literally did everything, but nothing changed. When I edit font size and change wdth and height ( as I say in pictures ) even though I make font size 1 , text is not appearing because too small text area. if I bigger the area it dont fit inside object. On the other hand, tried to change other objects scale but I could not fitted each other because game area should be 480x720. I dont think I could explain the error correctly, sorry. If you have another advice I can try.

Comment: if you make the font bigger you just need to adjust the 'Width' and 'Height' in the rect transform in the top right of the inspector to make space

Comment: I already tried it and it does not work. my text box's width : 2 and height : 1 . When I arrange this numbers I fits like I want. BUT it dont show texts even though I make font size: 1. because text box is too small to fit characters inside it.

Comment: text box width and height need to be much larger than 2 and 1, the text scale should be 1,1,1

Comment: thank you I solved. I upvoted your answer because you tried to help. thanks.